# WPF Message Pump Queue Is Not Processed Fast Enough

Tags: c#, wpf, input, message-queue

I am creating a WPF application with custom TreeView and manually implement the collapse, expand, collapse subtree, expand subtree events. By "expand subtree" I mean expanding the tree node and all of its children recursively, just like what happens when you press "*" on a regular Windows tree view.

My problem is, that my expand/collapse handlers can take a relatively long time to finish for certain trees. This allows the users for example to repeatedly issue a consecutive collapse subtree and expand subtree command pair over and over again. Thus, even after they stop mashing the keys, the event queue still contains these events and they will be processed seconds after the user has stopped entering any input.

This can happen also when scrolling through the content: the up, down, page up, page down, etc events are processed by the message pump seconds after the input device has physically stopped reporting inputs.

**I wonder what can be done to prevent this behavior and stop processing queued up input.** This is also a problem for using already existing features, like pressing the UP, DOWN, PAGE UP, PAGE DOWN keys, where I did not implement any custom logic.

I've tried checking if the key is actually down when processing, but it does not help. It seems the Keyboard class reflects the states in the message pump, not physically checking the keyboard.

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    //)
    if (e.Key == Key.Multiply && Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Multiply)) // Do a custom expand subtree
    {
        // ...
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    else if (e.Key == Key.Divide && Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Divide)) // Do a custom collapse subtree
    {
        // ...
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Any idea is welcomed. Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
I would like to point out, *that this problem is all over in Windows.* It's not just the code I wrote.

For instance, open the Registry Editor (regedit.exe), find HKEY_USERS, select it, and smash expand all (hotkey: *) then collapse (hotkey: -) a couple of time: behold the unresponsive UI. You can hit an UP or DOWN at the end of your `*-*-*-` sequence and experience the selection change after a couple of seconds when the expand/collapse cycle has finished.

Comment: How about setting a wait cursor to let the user know to wait?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes, that can be done, but that does not prevent processing the user input in the message queue and just like with RegEdit, it will cause the UI to hang.

Comment: @HansPassant *"You are subjecting your user to enough torture already, don't make it worse."* how does this help? If you have an opinion, why it is wrong, even better, how it could be done better, please let us know. Otherwise, your comment is worthless as you do not add anything to the case.

Comment: You could try "stacking" the expand commands(no actual processing) and process them only once. After no additinal commands were queued for say 200ms?

Comment: @user6144226 Yes, that's actually something worth trying. Reducing the time spent in the event handler to not exceed the time delay between the repeat delay of the key pressed event.

Comment: This is perfect for throttling: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229400(v=vs.103).aspx